# After cancelling the file uploading,shows the name?

Tags: angularjs

I want to remove the file name,if cancel button is clicked.
my code is :

```
<div layout="row" class="noPadding">
      <p class="md-body-1 bold underline">Download CSV</p>
      <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="showBulkEntries()">
        <label for="file-upload-input-{{themeObj.name}}" style="color:green">Browse</label> 
      </md-button>
      <input type = "file" id="file-upload-input-{{themeObj.name}}" file-model = "mcqEditCtrl.fileUploadObj['{{themeObj.name}}'].csvUploadFile" ng-hide="inputHide=true" ngf-pattern="'*.csv'" accept="application/csv" multiple/>
      <label class="md-body-1">{{mcqEditCtrl.fileUploadObj[themeObj.name].csvUploadFile.name}}</label>
      <md-button flex-offset="5" class="md-hue-3 md-raised" ng-click="mcqEditCtrl.uploadFile(themeObj)">Preview/Upload</md-button>


    </div>
```

Comment: Just a side note- change `file-model = "mcqEditCtrl.fileUploadObj['{{themeObj.name}}'].csvUploadFile"` to `file-model = "mcqEditCtrl.fileUploadObj[themeObj.name].csvUploadFile"`

Comment: `document.getElementById("fileInput").files === undefined` if the user clicks cancel.